# Why pthread_self is marked with attribute(const)?

Tags: c, gcc, pthreads, glibc

In Glibc's `pthread.h` the `pthread_self` function is declared with the `const` attribute:

```
extern pthread_t pthread_self (void) __THROW __attribute__ ((__const__));
```

In GCC [that attribute means](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes):

> Many functions do not examine any values except their arguments, and have no effects except the return value. Basically this is just slightly more strict class than the pure attribute below, since function is not allowed to read global memory.

I wonder how that's supposed to be? Since it does not take any argument, `pthread_self` is therefore allowed only to *always return the same value*, which is obviously not the case. That is, I would have expected `pthread_self` to read global memory, and therefore eventually be marked as `pure` instead:

> Many functions have no effects except the return value and their return value depends only on the parameters and/or global variables. Such a function can be subject to common subexpression elimination and loop optimization just as an arithmetic operator would be. These functions should be declared with the attribute pure.

The implementation on x86-64 seems to be actually reading global memory:

```
# define THREAD_SELF \
  ({ struct pthread *__self;                                           \
     asm ("mov %%fs:%c1,%0" : "=r" (__self)                            \
          : "i" (offsetof (struct pthread, header.self)));             \
     __self;})

pthread_t
__pthread_self (void)
{
  return (pthread_t) THREAD_SELF;
}
strong_alias (__pthread_self, pthread_self)
```

Is this a bug or am I not seeing something?

Comment: It'll always return the same value *in a given thread*. If you call a pure function, change a global variable, and then call it again, you might get a different return value. If you don't change a global variable in between and the parameters are the same, the compiler can assume the return value will be the same. This cannot happen with a `__const__` function like `pthread_self()` because the return value doesn't depend on the value of any global variables. The fact that it'll return a different value in a different thread isn't really relevant to what's happening here.

Comment: That memory is not actually global, it is in the `%fs` segment, that is a special segment usually dedicated to thread local storage. So it is actually accessing thread local memory.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: IOW there are interactions with `pure`-ness and `const`-ness and multithreading. Fair enough, but that doesn't explain how `pthread_self` can be implemented without even reading any global memory?

Comment: @peppe: It doesn't really matter. `pthread_self()` returns the thread ID of the calling thread, and that never changes over the life of the thread. It is defined that way. If it does change, your implementation is broken, so all bets are off. If you do something weird to break it, then you invoke undefined behavior, so all bets are equally off. You personally cannot make a global variable which will change that value without doing something so strange as to render you not entitled to rely on that guarantee. Even if it did read global memory, it does so in a way that has no observable effects.

Comment: Well it *does* matter if you use an attribute and then violate the conditions then that allow the usage of said attribute. That's pretty much the question here...

Comment: @rodrigo: a-ha, interesting, that would explain it. Mind posting as a full answer?

Comment: See above. You cannot violate the conditions. That's the point. How do you propose to make a global variable which changes what `pthread_self()` will return?

Comment: Why you "cannot violate the conditions"? What if you have a global data structure containing a bunch of `pthread_t`s, that you access with some thread local key?

Comment: @peppe: If you personally make a global data structure containing a bunch of `pthread_t`s, `pthread_self()` is not going to read from it, so you can change it however you like. If you go poking around the internals of the pthreads library and change whatever you want, you're not entitled to rely on *any* of the guarantees it provides, not just this one, any more than you'd be able to if you rewrote and recompiled it. You can cast away `const`ness from any variable, but if you do that, it's no good complaining that your `const` guarantee wasn't honored, because you broke it yourself.

Comment: @peppe: I wouldn't mind, but the `%fs` thing is not so relevant to the `const` vs `pure` debate, and that is the real topic here. In Intel architectures, usually `%fs` points to a segment in memory that holds the current _thread descriptor_. It is a structure with a lot of information about the current thread. That structure is also available from the global data segment `%ds`, but the nice thing about `%fs` is that it is different in each  thread context, so you always get the current thread descriptor at address `%fs:0`.

Answer (score 4):

The attribute was most likely added in the assumption that GCC would only use it locally (within a function), and would never be able to use it for inter-procedural optimizations. Today, some of Glibc developers are questioning the correctness of the attribute exactly because powerful inter-procedural optimization could, potentially, lead to miscompilation; quoting [post by Torvald Riegel to Glibc developers' mailing list](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2016-04/msg00303.html),

> The const attribute is specified as asserting that the function does not
>   examine any data except the arguments.  __errno_location has no
>   arguments, so it would have to return the same values *every time*.
>   This works in a single-threaded program, but not in a multi-threaded
>   one.  Thus, I think that strictly speaking, it should not be const.
>
> We could argue that this magically is meant to always be in the context
>   of a specific thread.  Ignoring that GCC doesn't define threads itself
>   (especially in something like NPTL which is about creating a notion of
>   threads), we could still assume that this works because in practice, the
>   compiler and its passes can't leak knowledge across a function used in
>   one thread and other one used in another thread.

(`__errno_location()` and `pthread_self()` both are marked with `__attribute__((const))` and receive no arguments).

Here's a small example that could plausibly be miscompiled with powerful interprocedural analysis:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void *errno_pointer;

static void *thr(void *unused)
{
  if (!errno_pointer || errno_pointer == &errno)
    abort();
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  errno_pointer = &errno;
  pthread_t t;
  pthread_create(&t, 0, thr, 0);
  pthread_join(t, 0);
}
```

(the compiler can observe that `errno_pointer` is static, it does not escape the translation unit, and the only store into it assigns the same "const" value, given by `__errno_location()`, that is tested in `thr()`). I've used this example in [my email asking to improve documentation of pure/const attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2015-09/msg00354.html), but unfortunately it didn't get much traction.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer (and the links), this is confirming to me that the documentation for `const` and `pure` is absolutely not clear in a multithreaded environment...

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder how that's supposed to be?

This attribute is telling the compiler that *in a given context* `pthread_self` will always return the same value. In other words, the two loops below are exactly equivalent, and the compiler is allowed to optimize out the second (and all subsequent) calls to `pthread_self`:

```
// loop A
std::map<pthread_t, int> m;
for (int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
  m[pthread_self()] += 1;

// loop B
std::map<pthread_t, int> m;
const pthread_t self = pthread_self();
for (int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
  m[self] += 1;
```

> The implementation on x86-64 seems to be actually reading global memory

No, it does not. It reads *thread-local* memory.

Comment: I know that that's the ultimate purpose of the `const` and `pure` attributes, but again, this doesn't quite explain why `const` and not `pure`. ... is the documentation just wrong about those semantics? Can `f` in `const char array[] = "Hello, world!"; char f(int i) { return array[i]; }` be marked as `const` or `pure`? The documentation says `pure`, everybody here is saying `const`.